# pydev editor string color

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Just upgraded to pydev 4.4.0.2015100523 and window->preferences->PyDev->Editor list "Appearance color options" does not include "Strings" although the web page (http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_editor_prefs.html) for PyDev Editor Preferences lists it (between self and Comments): where's it gone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it in `Bytes`. If you change the color of it, changes the color of strings.[image]

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of Bytes for strings! Maybe the web site help could be updated

Comment: You're welcome! if it solved your problem please accept the answer so you can close the question ;)

Comment: @tobiz I am sure that PyDev would gladly accept a pull request. I think the screenshot in question that is out of date is here: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/com.python.pydev.docs/merged_homepage/final/images/editor/editor_preferences.png